# How to create an index for fields which can be missing at Couchbase 7.1

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to create an index for fields which can be missing at Couchbase 7.1

Even if I use an example from the Couchbase documentation, I have a syntax error: INCLUDE (reserved word)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_airport_include
ON `travel-sample`.inventory.airport(district INCLUDE MISSING, name);
```

I tried to enclose the reserved words inside backticks, but without success:

```
`INCLUDE` `MISSING`, `INCLUDE MISSING`
```

Any ideas how to create that kind of index ?

Comment: are you using >=7.1.2? this seems to only be available for 7.1.2 or later https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/createindex.html#include-missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mathew Groves mentioned INCLUDE MISSING attribute is only available in 7.1.2 or later versions

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/createindex.html#include-missing

Comment: I've checked that I have 7.1.1, so this functionality is not available. Thanks for help!

Comment: You can upgrade to 7.1.3